# Contar elementos de un numpy array en un intervalo

Tags: python, numpy

tengo una duda y la verdad no se como hacerlo, tengo que contar la cantidad de veces que se repite un número dentro de un intervalo. El arreglo es el siguiente:

```
datos = np.array([0.525,0.546,0.522,0.577,0.563,0.572,0.558,0.56,0.508,0.562,0.564,0.537,0.574,0.586])
```

y los intervalos con el resultado que tiene que salir son:

```
INTERVALO   RESULTADO
0.5-0.51    1
0.51-0.52   0
0.52-0.53   2
0.53-0.54   1
0.54-0.55   1
0.55-0.56   1
0.56-0.57   4
0.57-0.58   3
0.58-0.59   1
```

Alguien sabe como hacerlo, estaba pensando en separar `datos` en sub-arreglos utilizando `np.split` pero de ahí ya no se que más hacer, les agradecería mucho de nuevo su ayuda, ya que esto me tiene atorado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No te compliques con `np.split` o filtros boleanos, lo que buscas es [`numpy.histogram`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html):

```
import numpy as np

datos = np.array(
    [0.525, 0.546, 0.522, 0.577, 0.563, 0.572, 0.558,
     0.56, 0.508, 0.562, 0.564, 0.537, 0.574, 0.586]
     )

bins = [0.50, 0.51, 0.52, 0.53, 0.54, 0.55, 0.56, 0.57, 0.58, 0.59]
counts, bin_edges = np.histogram(datos, bins)

print(f"INTERVALO     CONTADOR")
for low, hight, count in zip(bin_edges, np.roll(bin_edges, -1), counts):
    print(f"{f'{low}-{hight}': <10}    {count}")
```

---

> ```
> INTERVALO     CONTADOR
> 0.5-0.51      1
> 0.51-0.52     0
> 0.52-0.53     2
> 0.53-0.54     1
> 0.54-0.55     1
> 0.55-0.56     1
> 0.56-0.57     4
> 0.57-0.58     3
> 0.58-0.59     1
> ```

Comment: Muchas, muchísimas gracias no sabia que fuera tan fácil.